# How to create dynamic Linq-to-Entities especially when number of col can change

Tags: entity-framework

I was trying to create a dynamic query in Linq-to-Entities (I am using 2012 and SQL Server 2005)

Following are the details.

```
create table t1(t1id int, col1 datetime, col2 varchar(500),col3 int)
```

There are following cases.

1. Columns of select and where clause can change.
2. Columns of select , where and group by can change.

Example #1:

```
Select col1, col2 
from t1 
where col3 = 1 
  and co1 between '01 jan 2009' and '31 dec 2013'
```

Example #2:

```
Select col1, count(col2) 
from t1 
where col3 = 1 
  and co11 between '01 jan 2009' and '31 dec 2013'
group by co11
```

And i would like to formulate above as follows in 2012 (linq to entity)

```
" select "+ @selectclause + " from t1  where " + whereclause
```

Yours sincerely

Comment: Do you want to return a collection of the same type for all possible queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Linq to Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964) where and Select clauses Take Expressions.
[Iqueryable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) where is defined as:

```
 public static IQueryable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
```

Orderby uses a similar Expression.
So you need to construct these expressions dynamically

- Option a  [System.Linq.Dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/bb894665.aspx)
  Probably the easiest to learn. With good flexibility
  This allows you to pass strings via an Extension.
  The string expressions get converted to `Expression<Func<>>`
  [Blog on using System.linq.Dynamic](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)
- Option B [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx)
  Best alround approach.
  LinqKit provides some clever tools that allow you to construct expressions
- Option C
  Hardcore EXpression tree construction.
  [System.Linq.Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.aspx)  Powerful yet Complex.

Combining options A ,B and/or C,  is also possible.